# spring application can't find mapped view

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, generics

In my spring application, I have one generic controller class with serve as base class for several other controllers in my application. These derived controllers have this structure:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="usuario")
public class UsuarioController extends controller<Usuario> {

    public UsuarioController() {
        super(Usuario.class);
    }

}
```

I will have one of this for each entity class from my application. In the generic controller, I have two methods for each action (ie.: insert, update, delete, select). this two methods (and the generic controller) have this form:

```
public class controller<E> {

    @Autowired
    private service<E> serv;

    private final Class<E> entityClass;

    @RequestMapping(value="cadastra")
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_'+#this.this.name)")
    public ModelAndView cadastra() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return new ModelAndView("privado/"+this.entityClass.getName()+"/cadastra", "command", this.entityClass.newInstance());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="cadastra", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String cadastra(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result) {
        if(serv.cadastra(object))
            return "yes";
        else
            return "not";
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run the application, and try access the view mapped by this method, I am getting a 404 error.

Anyone can tell what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Please show an example of a concrete view that you have. Also post your Spring MVC configuration

Comment: @geoand my spring configuration: https://github.com/klebermo/blog.cms/tree/master/src/main/java/com/config/app.

Comment: Why don't you update your question so everyone can easily see the configuration?

Comment: @geoand I keep my views here: https://github.com/klebermo/blog.cms/tree/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp (the view I try access and it's mapped by the controller above is privado/Usuario/).

Comment: sorry, I thought that were the simpler way, since my configuration is placed in several classes.

Comment: I take it that for `UsuarioController`, the JSP view should be `/privado/Usario/cadastra.jsp`. Correct? You have made sure that `this.entityClass.getName()` returns that value?

Comment: @geoand Ok, that's the problem: I just needed change `this.entityClass.getName()` for `this.getName()` - I had created this method just for get the correct value in another place and forgot change here.

Comment: Ok, I will add it as answer for future viewers to easily find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Spring cannot locate the correct JSP to forward the processing. After reviewing your code it seems that you need to change `this.entityClass.getName()` with `this.getName()`